# java turning a large file into byte arrays and recreating it in another computer

Tags: java, file, buffer

i m working on a project in which i need to send a big pdf file (10mbits) to a another computer, but first i need to break into smaller byte arrays of 32000 bits in order to fit in the packets.Then the other computer will need to remake the file.I ve already managed to break it but i m having difficulties recreating  it.

That's what i ve done till now :

`class Example {
public static byte [] buffer = new byte [8];
public static byte [] ArrayCheck = { 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
public static int count =0;

public static void main (String [] args) throws Exception{
            int n = 32000;
            int temp = 4000;
            int counter =0;
            byte [] chunk = new byte [n] ;
            System.out.println("it worked"  +chunk.length);
            RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile("SimpleExample.pdf", "r");
            byte[] b = new byte[(int)f.length()];
            f.read(b);

            System.out.println("it worked"  +b.length);
            for (int pos = 0; pos < b.length; pos+=n ) {
                if ((pos+n)>b.length){

                 temp =(((pos+n)-b.length)/8+((pos+n)-b.length)%8);

                System.arraycopy(b, pos, chunk , 0, temp);    // this is the last packets
                CreateFile(chunk);
                }else { 
                System.arraycopy(b, pos, chunk , 0, temp);
                CreateFile(chunk);
                }
                counter ++;

            }
            System.out.println(counter);

}

public static void CreateFile (byte [] data ) throws Exception{

FileOutputStream sigfil = new FileOutputStream("example.pdf", true);
            System.arraycopy(data, 3998, buffer , 0, 1); 

                        sigfil.write(data);
                if (Arrays.equals(buffer,ArrayCheck)) {
                sigfil.close();
                count++;
                System.out.println(count);
                }
            }`

}

How do i do that?

Comment: `but first i need to break into smaller byte arrays of 32000 bits in order to fit in the packets.` What packets are these?

Comment: its a research project, so they are not actually IP packets. One guess about my problem was that the last sent packet will have some extra bits as "0" so probably i ll need to take them off before i put them to the writer ?

Comment: The problem is not tcp or udp its about breaking the file and reconstructing it.Somehow eventually the chunk array of 32000 bits will be delivered to the recipient, so my question is how am i going to create a file in which i will reconstruct it from lots of 32000 bits.whats the best solution?